# Jenkins Setup for Selenium Grid to run automation on iOS devices

Tags: node.js, selenium, jenkins, appium, selenium-grid

I am trying to perform automation on two iOS devices using Appium and Selenium Grid. I am able to perform the automation on my local machine.

At the moment I am trying to configure the settings to run the same using Jenkins Machine.

I have created a maven project on Jenkins and I am launching the hub and the nodes on my local machine and performing the Automation.

Is there any way to run the Hub and Register the nodes to the hub through Jenkins. Rather than running on my local machine.

Machine: MAC OSX

Root to Hub: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig hub.json

Node 1: node appium -a localhost -p  4567 --udid f373abcc456aa185c042c2d49be8b11bebbf446b  --tmp /tmp/ipad --nodeconfig "Path/To/Json" -g "Path/to/log" --session-override

Node 2: node appium -a localhost -p  4568 --udid f373abcc456aa185c042c2d49be8b11bebbf446b  --tmp /tmp/ipad --nodeconfig "Path/To/Json" -g "Path/to/log" --session-override

Can someone please help me how to run above Hub and Nodes through Jenkins.
These are Pre-Build Steps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. There is just a fair amount of configuration you need to do.

***Running Hub and Nodes on same machine:***

1. While configuring `Jenkins`, there is an option of `Add Build Steps` where you can select `Execute Shell`. Refer [here](http://puu.sh/oAker/cb7158e794.png). There you can write the command to run the command to start `hub`. I am assuming that the `Jenkins` machine has `Java` installed and it also has the hubConfig file named `hub.json` present.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig hub.json
```

2. In the similar fashion you can run the commands to start your `Node1` and `Node2`. You have already mentioned the command there.

Once the `hub` and `nodes` are running, you can go ahead and run your build commands.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried this option. Firstly I have created a maven project and in the pre build steps I have configured them. I have tried to cd to folder and gave the steps to perform the task.